# How do you get the variable name rather than the value?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I would like print statement to return the variable used which is model_3 in this case rather than returning b.

An example would be :

```
    model_1 = 'a' 
    model_2 = 'c'
    model_3 = 'b' 
    model_4 = 'f'
    model_5 = 'e' 
    
    models = [model_1, model_2, model_3, model_4, model_5]
        

    print(locals().keys()) #returns all local keys
    print(models.__contains__(model_3)) # True only if model_3 was used
    print(models.__contains__("model_3")) # False since the value is b
        
    print(models) # returns ['a','c','b','f','e']
    print (models) #desired output [model_1, model_2, model_3, model_4, model_5]
```

Is it possible to pop only the variable name not the values itself?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to pop only the variable name not the values itself?

No, because the list does not contain the *variables*, but rather the *values* they had at the time you constructed the list.  Consider this variation on your code:

```
    model_1 = 'a'
    model_2 = 'b'
    model_3 = 'c'
    models = [model_1, model_2, 'c']

    model_1 = 'd'

    print(models.__contains__(model_1)) # False, because model_1 now has a different value
    print(models.__contains__(model_2)) # True
    print(models.__contains__(model_3)) # True; the current value of 'model_3' was added directly
    print(models.__contains__('a'))     # True; this was added as 'model_1'
    print(models.__contains__('b'))     # True; this was added as 'model_2'
    print(models.__contains__('c'))     # True
    print(models.__contains__('d'))     # False, even though this is now the value of model_1
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming that I cannot use the variables and offering a different solution. This would work on a different case, but unfortunately not the current one I'm working on.

Comment: @MarthaF, the code presented is intended to be demonstrative of the language semantics, not a solution to the question posed.  It is supplementary to the actual answer, which is summed up in my first word: "no."